# Как можно сгенерировать случайную позицию для опорного элемента быстрой сортировки не используя функцию rand?

Tags: c++, алгоритм, сортировка

Как можно сгенерировать случайную позицию для опорного элемента быстрой сортировки не используя функцию rand? Другие стратегии выбора не подходят из за специфики задания.

```
#include <iostream>
   
size_t random_position(){
//
}

template <typename T, typename Comparator = std::less<T>>
size_t partition(T* arr, size_t left, size_t right, Comparator cmp = Comparator()){
    std::swap(arr[left + random_position() % (right - left)], arr[right]);
    T piv = arr[right];
    size_t left_iter, right_iter;
    size_t i = left;
    for (; cmp(arr[i], piv); i++);
    left_iter = right_iter = i;
    while(true)
    {
        while(cmp(piv, arr[right_iter]))
            right_iter++;
        if (right_iter == right) {
            std::swap(arr[left_iter], arr[right]);
            return left_iter;
        }
        else{
            std::swap(arr[right_iter], arr[left_iter]);
            right_iter++;
            left_iter++;
        }
    }
}


template <typename T, typename Comparator = std::less<T>>
T QuickSelect(T* arr, size_t k, size_t left, size_t right, Comparator cmp = Comparator()){
    while (left != right){
        size_t piv_pos = partition(arr, left, right, cmp);
        if (piv_pos == k)
            return arr[piv_pos];
        else if (piv_pos > k)
            right = piv_pos - 1;
        else
            left = piv_pos + 1;
    }
    return arr[k];
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7602919/how-do-i-generate-random-numbers-without-rand-function

Comment: Написать свой rand? [Линейный конгруэнтный метод](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D1%8D%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ну всегда же есть `rand` заменители, например:

```
LAGRE_INTEGER value;
::QueryPerformanceCounter(&value);

const int num = value % 1000;
```